# php extension pecl installs suffix error

Tags: php, linux, pecl, igbinary

I have a php instance on Webuzo (centos-6-x86_64.openvz) in `/usr/local/apps/php54/`. It already has pecl and phpize in   `/usr/local/apps/php54/bin/`. When installing igbinary with command

```
`/usr/local/apps/php54/bin/pecl install igbinary`
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
"WARNING: php_bin /usr/local/apps/php54/bin/php appears to have a suffix 54/bin/php, 
 but config variable php_suffix does not match"
```

Full log

```
# /usr/local/apps/php54/bin/pecl install igbinary
downloading igbinary-1.2.1.tar ...
Starting to download igbinary-1.2.1.tar (Unknown size)
..........................done: 229,376 bytes
9 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin /usr/local/apps/php54/bin/php appears to have a suffix 54/bin/php, but   config variable php_suffix does not match
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
shtool at '/tmp/pear/temp/igbinary/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Here's a config list of pecl: `sudo /usr/local/apps/php54/bin/pecl config-show`

```
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/local/apps/php54/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /etc/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
```

I have set php_suffix to `/usr/local/apps/php54/bin/php` using `sudo pear config-set php_suffix 54/bin/php` but that would cause a failure for phpize.

Answer (score 0):

Update the temp_dir for pecl

```
mkdir /root/tmp
pear config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
```

Install again. Let me know the results.